# Was there any investigation into Quirrell's death?

Tags: harry-potter

As I recall, after the first book, Professor Quirrell is never even as much as mentioned until *Order of the Phoenix*. At the end of the first book, we were told that the events surrounding Harry getting the stone are a secret. However, it seems strange to me that a man's unexpected death - by the hands of one of his students in a forbidden corridor - never got any official questioning. My suspicion peaked during chapter 15 of *Order of the Phoenix*, where Harry declares to Umbridge, a ministry official, that:

> “*Yeah, Quirrell was a great teacher,*” said Harry loudly, “*there was just that minor drawback of him having Lord Voldemort sticking out of the back of his head*.”

Obviously, this is a big deal. Is this knowledge that the ministry has? Was there any official explanation at all? If the ministry does know about this, then it's either a very inconvenient fact or yet another thing that they should be (at least trying to be) getting Harry in trouble for.

Comment: Dumbledore mentions that he was killed by Voldemort, but I'm not sure who he says it to.

Comment: @eyesplice17 As of OotP, it's hard to believe that they'll buy that excuse. They didn't even buy it for Cedric.

Comment: perhaps that's one explanation - the ministry did not want to (officially?) know Voldemort exists again

Comment: @eyesplice17 If there's evidence, then I want to see it. At face value, a man has died under suspicious circumstances and nothing was done.

Comment: We don't know that nothing was done; all we know is what Harry knows, and there is every reason to believe that the staff has no interest in keeping students in the loop for this.

Comment: Was there ever an inquiry into Cedric's death, for that matter?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Fudge gives an excuse at the end of Goblet of Fire. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Quirrell died after circumventing the magical defenses set up to protect the Philosopher's Stone.

Even if no one believes that Voldemort possessed Quirrell, the fallback position from that one would be that Quirrell himself attempted to steal the Stone, and was foiled in the attempt by Harry...*somehow*.

At the time of Quirrell's death, the Ministry had no need to discredit Harry and he was a generally popular figure as "The Boy Who Lived".  He was also 11 years old.  So a *hostile* investigation was not in the cards.  A superficial investigation friendly to the 11 year old popularly beloved orphan would conclude that Quirrell was a thief who got what was coming to him.  Case closed!

Comment: ["Damien: Omen II"](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi1788870937?ref_=tt_pv_vi_aiv_1) meets Harry Potter.

Answer (score 2):

In other [similar questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168895/what-did-dumbledore-tell-everyone-about-quirrells-death), there are explanations at what could have Dumbledore told to the Ministry (or everyone else, for that matter).

---

The Ministry has an unpleasant habit of overlooking investigations, botching them or rushing to conclusions. Specially when they don't want to know the truth.

Should we remember when Harry was automatically guilty for a levitation spell performed by a certain domestic elf? Or the Sirius unfair incarceration with no trial? Or when Hagrid was expelled with no investigation at all? Or when Tom Riddle got away for killing his father and his family, putting the blame on Morfin Gaunt? Or when they in purpose ignored the return of Voldemort for a whole year because the alternative was too scary?

And these are only the cases that I can remember right now. I'm pretty sure there are a lot more that I'm not mentioning.

---

In the unlikely scenario that the Ministry would've decided to look onto the matter of Quirrell dying, I highly doubt that they would've done it in a detail level that would've allowed them to detect the Voldemort's possession (assuming it can be detected after Voldemort left the body), or even bothered to determine the true cause of his death.

Quirrell death was even more evident than previous investigations (Sirius, Hagrid, Morfin...). He just died trying to steal the Philosopher Stone. His charred body could be the unfortunate product of a potent curse put in place to protect the Stone, and Harry just witnessed it, since he's just a first-year boy with little lethal capacity.

Comment: Persuasive, but isn't this answer entirely speculation?

Comment: @J.Mini Unfortunately, there's no canon answer about if the Ministery looked onto the death of Quirrell.